# Capability to revert my edit rejection or approval?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits

Is it possible to revert my rejection/approval of an edit?

Basically after rejecting an edit on a post, I realize that the edit really should be accepted. So, I'd like to change my rejection to an approval (or visa versa).

This could be for any edit that requires approval before it has been posted.

Here is the screen that I'm referring to:

[image]

Would this be something that could be implemented in the future? (Or Perhaps I'm missing how to do this already)

Comment: Rejection of an edit on your own post, right?

Comment: @rene I updated my question to hopefully be a bit more clear. It could be any edit, not just my own post.

Comment: Those edits already need at least 3 votes. So if you mis-click, it need at least two others to make the same mistake. That feels as enough safe-guarding, no need to introduce something complex like re-doing an review

Comment: @rene Makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: If you're concerned about your reviewing against your peers, you might find the [review consensus script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508) handy.

Comment: @rene That's pretty cool. It's more of a first time "well poo" mis-click, so I thought about the feature. I don't typically make this type of error when reviewing.

Comment: And it looks like your *mishap* got resolved by others ... the system works...